# Find the second closest index to value

Tags: python, numpy

I am using

```
index = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
```

to find the index in an array with the smallest absolute difference to a value.

However, is there a nice clean way such as this for finding the *second* closest index to the value?

Comment: I would doubt it, to be honest! You could get sorted differences and index the second smallest.

Comment: What should be returned if two indexes are equally close to the value?

Comment: @ajcr, Well I guess the second value to be picked would be the one that argmin() didn't choose (I don't know how argmin() goes about choosing in the first place)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this works

```
a = np.linspace(0,10,30)
array([  0.        ,   0.34482759,   0.68965517,   1.03448276,
         1.37931034,   1.72413793,   2.06896552,   2.4137931 ,
         2.75862069,   3.10344828,   3.44827586,   3.79310345,
         4.13793103,   4.48275862,   4.82758621,   5.17241379,
         5.51724138,   5.86206897,   6.20689655,   6.55172414,
         6.89655172,   7.24137931,   7.5862069 ,   7.93103448,
         8.27586207,   8.62068966,   8.96551724,   9.31034483,
         9.65517241,  10.        ])
n = np.pi
a[np.argsort(np.abs(a-n))[1]]
# Output 3.4482758620689657
# the closest value is 3.103...
```

Comment: I have tested this vs YXD answer of `a[np.argpartition(np.abs(a-n),1)[1]]` and plonser answer is faster and I don't know why.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the index of the kth smallest element of an array `a` without sorting the whole array using `argpartition`

```
np.argpartition(a, k)[k]
```

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html

Comment: This is certainly preferable for large arrays as it is `O(n)` in complexity (while regular full-sorting is typically `O(n*log(n))`) (+1).

Comment: Luckily the array is not very large at all, so I am using the above answer and its working, but thanks for providing a more efficient way, I have some large data sets this might be helpful for

Comment: What is `a`? What is `k`? How to implement it to solve OP question? Lots of question appears and your link about the documents also did not provide for the exact same question from the OP.